# Handlebars.js: Pass object properties as Ember.js component attributes

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'd like to pass the properties of an object as attributes of a component.

For instance, in the example below, I'm passing the object as an attribute `column` of the `dynamic-table-column` component.

```
<tr>
  {{#each column in table.columns}}
    {{dynamic-table-column column=column}}
  {{/each}}
</tr>
```

But could I do it if I wanted the properties of the `column` object to be passed as attributes to this component? React.js, for instance has a notation for this: `{...props}`.

**Update**

To clarify, I'll be more explicit about my current situation. Right now I have to repeat every attribute explicitly, as in:

```
<tr>
  {{#each column in table.columns}}
    {{dynamic-table-column
      title=column.title
      alignment=column.alignment
      sortable=column.sortable
      formatter=column.formatter}}
  {{/each}}
</tr>
```

Besides being too verbose, this has a fundamental flaw: imagine if a new attribute is added to the component in the future. We'd have to go over every place where this component is used, and add the new attribute explicitly.

React's JSX on the other hand, has a syntax for this purpose:

```
<DynamicTableColumn {...column}/>
```

That will assign each property in the `column` object to the attribute in the component with that same name. So if in the future the column object carries a new property, a new attribute will be assigned to the component, without having to change the template explicitly.

I hope this will make things clearer.

Comment: something like this ?
    {{dynamic-table-column columnName=column.name}}

Comment: If  you're looking for something like `{{dynamic-table-column (pass-attrs column 'name' 'desc')}}` then no, it doesnot exist.

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve? Why not just access them using `column.propertyName`

Comment: I could, I was just hoping to avoid to repeat every possible property in that object. As it is right now, I'd have to explicitly type `{{my-component title=column.title align=column.align sortable=column.sortable formatter=column.formatter ...}}` and by now I think you guys get the idea. Also, if some attribute gets added in the future, we'd have to go through every place where this component is used to add that attribute. And since React.js/JSX have a syntax for this, I thought maybe Handlebars has something equivalent too. I still hope so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible in Ember (Sep 2015).

Handlebars syntax does not support what we've called a "splat" operator, inspired by Ruby. There is a [proposal](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1050) with some support on their repo.

HTML-syntax components, `<my-component arg={{prop}} />` have not yet landed in Ember. When they do there will be an opportunity to introduce a helper for splat, ala `<my-component {{attrs someHash}} />`, however there is no specific proposal to track for this right now.